# How to choose in which ExecutorService the play ws is executed?

Tags: scala, playframework, threadpool

1)
I would like to execute specific Play WS in an isolated thread pool. Because I'm going to have a lot of HTTP call to do in background and I don't want that it overload my main executor service.

Note : I also found an information that I don't understand here : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/ibDf2vL3sT0
It explains that PlayWs already have it owns thread pool. Is it still right in Play 2.6 ? I don't understand things like that when reading the play documentation (see : https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ThreadPools#Using-the-default-thread-pool)

I created my own context :

```
call-to-db-context {
  fork-join-executor {
    parallelism-factor = 1
    parallelism-max = 24
  }
}
```

But I don't know how to specify that ws request use this context.

```
ws.url("http://127.0.0.1:8080/b")
  .get() // How to specify executorContext here ?
```

2)
Also, this call-to-db-context must have a low priority because it's background task. I would like that Akka handle user request have higher priority and my default executorContext too. What is the best way to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

In early play it was easier, you could just configure client yourself (as soon as WS was wrapper on top of ning).

It looks bit more complicated in 2.6. In mature products when something is not easy to change, than, most probably, you do not need to change it.

So, I do not think that you need to specify thread pool for WS methods. For post-processing may be, if it is long. But play client is asynchronous, means, that it will not block thread while wait for response. If you do requests using unreliable network, just use timeouts.

See [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaWS) more about play client

Not sure that understand your requirement about priority. Did you know about akka deployment configuration? If no, you need to read [here](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/general/configuration.html#actor-deployment-configuration)
So, you can specify thread pools for your actors. Having different dispatchers for actors and ws post-processing (processing of data from DB?) you will separate these functionalities. If ws-calls postprocessing is heavy, limit amount of threads for your `call-to-db-context` dispatcher

**Update after comment**

Lots of ws-calls in your case (if you think that their amount could affect perormance) need to be limited in two places: limit amount of calls started, limit amount of concurrent post-processing. You need to understand. Setting specific dispatcher for ws itself will not limit anything: as soon as it is async, it can start 1000 requests having only one thread.

So, I would say you can wrap your ws-calls into actor. Actor will handle message to start the request, and post-processing e.g.

```
receive: Receive = {
    …
    case Get(url) =>
        ws.url(url).get().onComplete {
            case Success(response) => self ! GetSuccess(response)
            case Failure(exception) => self ! GetFailure(exception) 
        }
    case GetSuccess(response) => …..
    case GetFailure(exception) => ……
}
```

you can deploy this actor on specific dispatcher with round robin pool (set amount of workers). This solution does not limit start of requests (so you can get long queue of responses). You can add become with disabling accepting Get, while not received GetSuccess or GetFailure (so worker need to process request completely before start next).

Comment: I already read these documentation from play. It doesn’t help me. My problem is that I have some asynchronous task to execute in order to respond to requests (including some ws call). On another side, i have a lots of ws call to do in background (volume depend on hour). So I don’t want that background ws calls slow request responses. So I need to isolate these call in a different thread pool and maybe give to this thread pool a low priority, isn’t it ?